# PHP Date Intervals using date_add

Tags: php, date

I have the following code which works on the first 2 lines, taking my start date, converting to unix timestamp, and then adding one day.

The 3rd line is trying to use the value that is then generated to use the date interval to find the date in 2 months.

Unfortunately, the date_add seems to return the error 'date_add() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, integer given'.

Can anyone tell me how I accomplish this using unix timestamp?

```
$startdate = strtotime('2014/12/19 15:00');
$weekstart = $startdate - (date("N",$startdate)*60*60*24)+(60*60*24);

$enddate = date_add($weekstart, DateInterval::createfromDateString('2 months'));
```

Comment: You're trying to mix UNIX timestamp functions and PHP's internal `DateTime` class methods.  Also, is there a specific reason you want to accomplish this only using UNIX timestamps?  A proper result is a proper result, is it not?

Comment: Then how can I accomplish this with unixtimestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you are wanting to create two different DateTime strings with different intervals. This should do it.

```
$startdate = new DateTime('2014/12/19 15:00');
$weekstart = $startdate->modify('+1 day');
$weekstart = $weekstart->format('U'); //change $weekstart to unix timestamp//

$enddate = $startdate->modify('+2 months');
$enddate = $enddate->format('U'); //change $enddate to unix timestamp//
```

Comment: `$enddate = $startdate->modify('+2 months');` will not copy modified DateTime object `$startdate` into new variable, only reference is copied, so you are still editing `$startdate`. Please keep that in mind.

Comment: I realized that also, I believe `$weekstart` object needs to be modified instead of `$startdate`. @user3189734, is `$enddate` what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

So use a DateTime:

```
$startdate = new DateTime('2014/12/19 15:00');
```

internally DateTime's constructor will be using strtotime() anyways, giving you all the benefits (and risk) of strtotime()'s parsing logic, plus all the benefits of having the entire DateTime object available from the get-go.

The rest of your datemath can be accomplished using pure DateTime operations as well,w ithout having to do manual 60*60*24-type stuff.